# In macOS Activity Monitor, why is "Applications in last 12 hours" grayed out / disabled?

Tags: macos, catalina, activity-monitor

Any idea why the "Applications in last 12 hours" is disabled in the "Activity Monitor"?

At one point it appeared briefly -- but after days of using it, it has since disappeared.

Using macOS 10.15.2. Many thanks.

[image: Activity Monitor - Applications in last 12 hours -- disabled]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only available on the Energy tab.

[image]

I can just tell from your pic, you're on the Disk tab.